# Get Poisson expectation of preceding values of a time series in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, statistics

I have some time series data (in a `Pandas` dataframe), *d(t)*:

```
time   1   2   3   4   ... 99  100
d(t)   5   3   17  6   ... 23  78
```

I would like to get a time-shifted version of the data, e.g. *d(t-1)*:

```
time   1   2   3   4   ... 99  100
d(t)   5   3   17  6   ... 23  78
d(t-1) NaN 5   3   17  6   ... 23
```

But with a complication. Instead of simply time-shifting the data, I need to take the *expected value* based on a Poisson-distributed shift. So instead of *d(t-i)*, I need E(*d(t-j)*), where *j* ~ Poisson(*i*).

**Is there an efficient way to do this in Python?**

Ideally, I would be able to dynamically generate the result with *i* as a parameter (that I can use in an optimization).

`numpy`'s Poisson functions seem to be about generating draws from a Poisson rather than giving a PMF that could be used to calculate expected value. If I could generate a PMF, I could do something like:

```
for idx in len(d(t)):
    Ed(t-i) = np.multiply(d(t)[:idx:-1], PMF(Poisson, i)).sum()
```

But I have no idea what actual functions to use for this, or if there is an easier way than iterating over indices. This approach also won't easily let me optimize over *i*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.stats.poisson` to get `PMF`.
Here's a sample:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson

mu = 10

# Declare 'rv' to be a poisson random variable with λ=mu
rv = poisson(mu)

# poisson.pmf(k) = (e⁻ᵐᵘ * muᵏ) / k!
print(rv.pmf(4))
```

For more information about `scipy.stats.poisson` check this [doc](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Scipy/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html).